# Should i use an old PSU for my new PC?

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, power

I have an old Antec Quattro 850w power supply which already has 6 years. I used the PC that this PSU was installed like 2/3 hours every day for 6 years, mainly for gaming.

I have a tight budget for my next PC, so I'm thinking of using this PSU for the new PC.

The PSU seems to work fine, no visible damange, but I'm not an electrical or electronic technician. I don't know if is safe to keep using it in a new computer ,I know that the PSU is good, but I don't know if it can have some normal damage for using it that much time.

Can this PSU ruin my new PC if something happens to it?

Should I open the PSU and look for any capacitor or other damaged component?

Should i just buy a new PSU?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eCtl.jpg]

Comment: It should be perfectly fine, grab a power supply tester if you're that worried: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16899261023

Antec is quite a good brand of PSU and unless it has some kind of bad history there's no good reason not to reuse it.

Comment: Reusing your PSU will be fine. If it's not causing you any problems now, there's no reason why you can't reuse it. It will never know the difference if you put it in a new home :)

Comment: If the PSU is working, and you are willing to accept the limitations of the PSU with regards to the newer power states, then there isn't a real reason not to use the PSU you already have.  If the PSU does die, and does take something out, something like that is normally covered by a warranty on the other parts ( since cascading failures shouldn't happen like that ).

Comment: Thanks for responses!, i am not worried anymore :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the short term - it should be fine, unless there's obvious issues. Its a high end PSU with a ton of *legs*. You do want a more modern PSU eventually - there's no support for [c6/c7 states in older PSUs](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1720613/haswell-compatible-psu-haswell-states.html), and that *may* cause issues, but the fix is trivial - turn off those states in bios if you have issues.

Typically when a PSU *does* die, it rarely takes out anything else. Your system might act up a little, or you might blow a fuse, but you just replace it, and things keep running.

Comment: Thanks!, i will check the c6/c7 states options in the new motherboard.